# Chrome packaged app; copy a fileEntry to user's download directory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

So in my app, there is a local storage (fileEntry) created by my app. I would like to add a feature to let user have access to the file. Since the app itself does not have access to the "Downloads" directory, currently I am using the following code:

```
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = obj.name;
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

where file is grabbed from `fileEntry.file(function (file){})`. The code works fine, but the problem is my file is huge (500MB) and when I create `createObjectURL` Chrome uses twice memory as the content is copied in the blob. The only thing I want is to "move" the file from the internal storage to user's "Downloads" directory. I know in extensions one can use the chrome.download API but this API is not available in packaged apps.

Comment: So, do you have an extension or app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [chrome.filesystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) and [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) apis instead. First, add the permissions to manifest.json:

```
permissions: [ "storage", { "fileSystem": [ "write", "retainEntries", "directory" ] } ]
```

Then get access to a folder on the actual filesystem and save it for later.

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({ type: "openDirectory" }, function(folder) {
 chrome.storage.local.set({ folder: chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry(folder) })
})
```

You can then restore it and use it like a normal directory entry.

```
chrome.storage.local.get("folder", function(storage) {
 chrome.fileSystem.restoreEntry(storage.folder, function(folder) {
  entry.moveTo(folder)
}) })
```

Comment: well, I have two main concerns with this approach. First, I am dong all the saving thing in the background.js; seems like you cannot call `chooseEntry` from background as it is not visible to users. Second, my app creates files in interaction with other apps/extensions meaning it is not a simple UI that user clicks on a button and then the browse window opens up. The app needs to be able to locate the file when a command is received whether it is from user or another extension/app

Comment: Will you want persistent access to the exported file? You can use chooseEntry from a hidden window created using hidden: true in the app creation options object.

Comment: I would like to have persistent access to the DirectoryEntry so that the app can create new files in the selected folder. Well, the idea is to show folder selector once to the user to define the save directory and then the app uses that folder as the default download directory. Is it possible?